# check all radio groups are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know best way to check all the radio button groups are checked in a page.
My code -

```
<div class="radioGroup">
    Question1
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="group1"/>1
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="group1"/>2
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="group1"/>3
    <input type="radio" value="4" name="group1"/>4
</div>

<div class="radioGroup">
    Question2
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="group2"/>1
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="group2"/>2
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="group2"/>3
    <input type="radio" value="4" name="group2"/>4
</div>

<div class="radioGroup">
    Question3
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="group3"/>1
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="group3"/>2
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="group3"/>3
    <input type="radio" value="4" name="group3"/>4
</div>

<input type="button" value="check all radio Group selected"  onclick="validate();"/>
```

and I wrote a javascript function which works fine but I want a good solution means single selector solution.

```
function validate(){
    var isNotSelected = false;
    $(".radioGroup").each(function(i,v){
        var grpName = $(this).find("input:first").attr("name");
        if($(this).find("[name='"+grpName+"']:checked").val() == undefined){
            isNotSelected  =true;   
        }
    });
    if(isNotSelected){
        alert("not all checked");   
    }
    else{
            alert("all checked");   
    }


}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use [HTML Labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

Comment: (arguable comment) the time spent investigating the solution is bigger than write the whole function. Sure you need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the number of total groups match the number of groups that contain a checked radio button, if so, all groups have been selected

```
$('.radioGroup').length === $('.radioGroup:has(input:checked)').length
```

Comment: My answer was simpler (and came many milliseconds before yours) :)

Comment: and it's not neccessary to use strict comparison

Comment: @dystroy - it was, and using `not` that way was clever

Comment: @KirillPisarev - `length` always returns a number, so why not ?

Comment: `===` is clearer than `==` in my opinion. I don't mind the extra conversion (all perf tests show it doesn't really matter) but having a strict comparison shows to the maintainer that both parts are supposed to be of the same type.

Comment: @dystroy thoughtless usage is not

Comment: If you can, always do strict, there's nothing wrong with being explicit !

Comment: @adeneo : both the solutions yours and dystroy are too good. Thanks for the wonder help..

Comment: @SaurabhMahajan - You're welcome, I like dystroy's answer better, and he was faster than me, so it should probably be the accepted one.

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
var allChecked = !$('.radioGroup:not(:has(:checked))').length;
```

[demonstration](http://jsbin.com/vegutifoxa/1/)